Script to open chromium in kiosk mode and inject JWT in localstorage
I’m making a web application for one of my university projects and I need that web app to run on Raspberry Pi.
To be more exact, I need that web app to run on startup  in Kiosk mode and I found resources on how to make that happen.
The problem I’m encountering is that I want to bypass the login form and to make a script which will send a post request with login body (credentials read from a locally stored file) to a login API on my server, get JWT in return and launch chromium on the url of my web application with that JWT in localstorage.
Right now I managed to make a script in python which will open the locally stored file and read from it, send the request and get the JWT. I also managed to get the chromium work in kiosk mode opening the web app url. The problem is that I dont know how to inject the JWT (tried with selenium but I get the notification on the top that it’s run by automated tool - I dont want that)
If anyone has a solution it would be great to learn from it and to finish university because this is one of my last projects there. Thank you guys!
